# Pass parameters to tf.py_function

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am creating a tf.data.Dataset, I have several preprocessing functions that I need to pass parameters to. Is it possible to pass parameters to functions via tf.py_function()?

The only way I can see to do it is to put my preprocessing functions inside a class, so that I can pass parameters in via self.

eg:

```
class My_Dataset():
    def __init__(self, shape):
        self.shape = shape

    def resize(self, image):
        # Note I am just using resize as a dummy example
        # my actual preprocessing functions are more general 
        # and take several params
        return cv2.resize(image.numpy(), self.shape)

    def get_map_func(self, image, label):
        [image,] = tf.py_function(self.resize, [image], [tf.float32])
        image.set_shape(shape)
        return image, label

    def create_dataset(self, images_paths, labels):
        ds = ...
        ds = ds.map(my_dataset.get_map_func)
        return ds

my_dataset = My_Dataset( (512, 512, 3) )

ds = my_dataset.create_dataset(...)
```

But is there a better way? I am always really cautious about passing classes to multiprocess functions. As I understand, they get pickled to the process so if the class gets too big then it always seems to cause me issues.

**Edit:** Adding Second question..

In the example above, does any instance of the my_dataset object actually exist in the final ds? For example, images_paths is a list millions of image paths tens of MB big. If I passed images_paths and labels into the class at **init** and assigned them to self, then would there be some massive object in ds that needs to get passed around between processes?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters by using a lambda function

Eg(illustrative):-

```
all_encoded_data = corpus_ds.map(lambda x: generate_context_target_pairs_map_fxn(x,window_size, vocab_size))
```

So here you can map on the main list and pass a lambda function to the mapper and call your tf.py_function wrapper. In case you have multiple values just zip them before mapping.